# Elasticsearch sort by count of nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following ES content, basically a list of product with nested offers from sites.

```
{
"product": {
  "ean": "abc",
  "features": {
     "product_type": "DVD player"
  },
  "color": "Black",
  "manufacturer": "Sony",
  "sitedetails": [
     {
        "name": "amazon.com",
        "sku": "zzz",
        "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/zzz"
     },
     {
        "name": "bestbuy.com",
        "sku": "aaa",
        "url": "http://www.bestbuy.com/aaa"
     }
  ],
  "category": "Portable DVD Players"
 },
 product: { etc etc},
 product: { etc etc},
}
```

How can I sort by the count of sitedetails?

tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example in the question, it seems like as a single document but it is not possible for a single json document to have multiple fields at the same level with the same name.

Hence, going ahead with the assumption that each `product` field represents a different top-level document

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {} 
  },
  "sort" : {
    "_script" : {
      "script": "doc['sitedetails'].values.size()",
      "order": "desc",
      "type" : "number"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `doc[...]` notation only allows access for simple valued fields. It cannot return a json object from it. Hence `doc['sitedetails']` will give error, which is why I used `_source` to extract the **sitedetails**.

Comment: ES 7.x version : `... script": "params['_source']['sitedetails'].size()", ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Painless, so you do not have to enable dynamic scripting.

```
{
  "sort": [{
    "_script": {
       "type": "number",
       "script": "params._source?.product?.sitedetails?.length ?: 0",
       "order": "desc"
     }
   }]
}
```

I also included handling for null fields. See
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/_operators.html

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20068

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Script Based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) to accomplish this as follows:

```
{
   "sort": {
      "_script": {
         "type": "number",
         "script": "_source.product.sitedetails.size()",
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add `script.inline: true` at the end of your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file for [enabling dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting). By default dynamic scripting is turned off in elasticsearch and you cannot execute scripts unless you turn it on.